# c++ seekp(0，ios::end) not working

Tags: c++, file, fstream

Apologize for my poor English.
I am stuck by `fstream` in C++. Here is my code.

```
#include<iostream>  
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

struct TestStruct
{
    int a;
    char str[30];
    TestStruct(int a_, const char* s)
    {
        a = a_;
        strcpy_s(str,sizeof(char)*30, s);
    }
    TestStruct() = default;
};

int main()
{
    fstream output("out.bin", ios::out|ios::binary);
    output.seekp(0,ios::end);
    cout << output.tellp() << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        TestStruct a(10*i, "asdadas");
        output.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), sizeof(a));
    }

    output.close();
    fstream input("out.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
    input.seekg(2 * sizeof(TestStruct), ios::beg);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        TestStruct a;
        input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), sizeof(a));
        cout <<"file_pointer"<<input.tellg()<<'\t'<<a.a << endl;
    }
}
```

I use `seekp(0,ios::end)` to add new entry in the file. So the file should get lager when I run this code. But actually the file haven't change at all.

Here is the output:

```
>     0                  <--tellp() always return 0
>     file_pointer108 20
>     file_pointer144 30
>     file_pointer180 40
>     file_pointer216 50
>     file_pointer252 60
```

Comment: Just a minor point: `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so `strcpy_s(str, 30, s);` will work just fine. However, those two `30`'s should really be a named constant.

Answer (score 2):

Add `ios::app` to the `output`'s flags. You won't need to do `output.seekp(0, ios::end);` then.

Comment: Thank you so much! `ios::app` is working.But I am still confused why `seekp(0,ios::end)` doesn't set the file pointer to the end.

Comment: Well, I'm confused too.

Comment: Oh,I found another strange thing.` tellp()` still return `0` after I use `ios:app`.

Comment: Finally I found a less decent solution. That is, use `ios::app` and `ios::ate` together .Now the `tellp()` return the right offset.

Answer (score 1):

While it may not seem like it `seekp(0, ios::end)` is actually working.

The reason it returns 0 is because you accidentally create a **new empty file**.

And the end cursor position of a new empty file is 0.

It creates a new file because of the file mode you use:

```
output("out.bin", ios::out|ios::binary);
```

[image]

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open